# Python Mechanize uplod script add_file not working

Tags: python, forms, file-upload, mechanize

I am having a problem uploading files to a form.  I have the following code entered in my python script and it runs without errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cookielib 
import urllib2
import mechanize
import os
import re
import json
import time

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.open("https://upload.page")
br.select_form(name="upload",method="post",action="index.php?page=upload",enctype="multipart/form-data")

br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
os.chdir('path/to/file')
filename0 = 'filename.2019.torrent'
br.form.add_file(open(filename0), 'application/x-bittorrent', filename0, name='torrent')
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

os.chdir('path/to/file')
filename1 = 'filename.2019.nfo'
br.form.add_file(open(filename1), 'text/plain', filename1, name='nfo')
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

os.chdir('path/to/file')
filename2 = 'filename.2019.jpg'
br.form.add_file(open(filename2), 'image/jpg', filename2, name='userfile')
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

br.submit()
```

I get the following form information.

```
<upload post https://upload.page multipart/form-data
  <HiddenControl(user_id=) (readonly)>
  <FileControl(torrent=<No files added>)>
  <FileControl(nfo=<No files added>)>
  <SelectControl(category=[* 25])>
  <FileControl(userfile=<No files added>)>
  <SubmitControl(submit=Send) (readonly)>>
```

this is not uploading my files and I can't find out why.  I have been working on this for days trying different things and googling my heart out.

text fields and radio buttons input is working properly, but not the add_file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I am assuming after doing some more searching, that it is because the site does employ javascript in a couple of places, but only to display different iframes, nothing to do with the submission.

If this is the case, is there anyway to ignore the scripts?  I have form fields in my script to cover what id hidden and displayed on the site with the javascript.

Thanks,